# Show only most recent date from joined MySQL table

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have 2 tables, a "document" table and a "content" table. They look like this (simplified):

```
document table:
docID
docTitle

content table:
contentID
docID
dateAdded
content
```

For every content change, a new record is inserted into the "content" table. This way there is a complete history of all changes. I would like to get a list of all the documents, with the latest content joined. It should return the docID, docTitle, and the associated content record with the newest "dateAdded" value. My brain is failing me right now, how would I create this join?

Comment: Perhaps rename this question to something more descriptive like "Show only most recent date from joined table" ?

Comment: @Gorgapor: Good call, I've updated the title.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This can be done with a subquery:

```
SELECT d.docID, docTitle, c.dateAdded, c.content
FROM document d LEFT JOIN content c ON c.docID = d.docID
WHERE dateAdded IS NULL
    OR dateAdded = (
        SELECT MAX(dateAdded)
        FROM content c2
        WHERE c2.docID = d.docID
    )
```

This is known as a ["groupwise maximum"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) query

Edit: Made the query return all document rows, with NULLs if there is no related content.

Comment: Thanks for the name. Whenever I have a SQL question, I never know what to Google for, which makes it more difficult to find a solution. :)

Comment: Would this query work when there are no content records for a document? I would still like it to list the document, and just return null for the dateAdded and content fields.

Comment: I would add LIMIT 1 to the subquery. There can be more than one record with the same `dateAdded` value in the `content` table. That would result in a failure. MySQL stores DATETIME with precision only to seconds, to this really can happen.A better solution would be to order by some unique order column, be it a primary key, or an arbitrary column that stores the order of the changes even in cases when the datetime precision is not sufficent.

Comment: The link you provided is awesome and helped me solve the situation I was in: `SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL
ORDER BY s1.article;` I'm so used to a LEFT JOIN causing more rows that I wouldn't have guessed to use a LEFT JOIN in such a manner where we filter by the right table being null, so basically we filter away the entire right side, then further restrict it by an extra condition on the ON clause. Brilliant approach!

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
SELECT t.docid, 
       t.docTitle, 
       mc.dateAdded, 
       mc.content
  FROM DOCUMENT t
  JOIN (SELECT c.docid,
               c.content,
               MAX(c.dateAdded)
          FROM CONTENT c
      GROUP BY c.docid, c.content) mc ON mc.docid = t.docid 
                                     AND mc.dateadded = t.dateadded
```

This should be faster than a correlated subquery.

Alternative for when there are no content records for a document:

```
   SELECT t.docid, 
          t.docTitle, 
          mc.dateAdded, 
          mc.content
     FROM DOCUMENT t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.docid,
                  c.content,
                  MAX(c.dateAdded)
             FROM CONTENT c
         GROUP BY c.docid, c.content) mc ON mc.docid = t.docid 
                                     AND mc.dateadded = t.dateadded
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do a simple join, and order by date added, and grab only the first record?

```
SELECT docTable.docId, docTable.docTitle from docTable
INNER JOIN content ON content.docID = docTable.contentID
WHERE docTable.docId = <some id>
ORDER BY content.dateAdded DESC
```

Comment: I thnk you want the order by to be DESC so the newest version is first.  Also if you add "LIMIT 1" you will get a single row.

Comment: Your right about the ordering. As for the limit, your also right, I just left that out because i was unsure of the database technology.  That command may vary (as far as I know).

Answer (score -1):

This is a 2 query solution:

First query:

```
select docID, max(dateadded) from [TblContent] group by docID
```

Second query:

```
select [TblDocument].* from [TblDocument]  
inner join [TblDocument] on [TblDocument].[Docid]=[FirstQuery].[DocID]
```

Comment: This would require a separate query for each row, not just two queries.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
select d.id, d.docTitle, MAX(c.dateAdd)
from document_table d
left join content_table c
on d.id = c.docId
group by d.id
```

Here is the thinking behind it: suppose document table has record A related to content(1, 2, 3, 4) and B related to (5, 6, 7, 8)

```
document        content

A               1
            2
                    3
            4

B               5
            6
            7
            8
```

a inner join with max(dateadded) will give you

```
document        content     max(dateadded)

A               1           1-1-2009...

A               2           1-1-2009...

A               3           1-1-2009...

A               4           1-1-2009...

B               5           2-1-2009...

B               6           2-1-2009...

B               7           2-1-2009...

B               8           2-1-2009...
```

after group by document id you will get

```
document    content     max(dateadded)

A           1           1-1-2009...

B           5           2-1-2009...
```

note: content id does not necessary match the id of the max dateadded

Comment: Is it possible to return documents that have no associated content records yet by changing this to an outer join, or will that change the behaviour? Also, can this return the contentID and content fields as well by including them in the select, or will that mess it up?

Comment: Is this My Sql?  Because if it isn't, depending on the database, you may not be able to select anything that is not in the group by clause.

Comment: you can do left join, but you can't put the contentID column there.

Comment: this solution does not "return ... the associated content record" as requested.

Comment: This works fine if you just want to display when was each document last updated - then you can use `MAX(date)`, but it won't guarantee the content of other columns from content table.