# MySQL SELECT COUNT() and then ORDER BY date

Tags: mysql, select, count

I've searched all over the place, but just can't seem to get the right way of phrasing my question to get the result I want (I'm sure it's really easy, but I've been smacking my head against it for ages!)

I have the following query:

```
SELECT co.title, co.content, co.id, bu.backupDate, bu.backupBy, COUNT(bu.id) AS totalBackups
FROM content co, wol_content_backup bu
WHERE co.car_model = '6-110'
AND co.subcategory = 'introduction'
ORDER BY bu.backupDate DESC
```

content contains an article's content, and wol_content_backup contains backups of the articles. bu.backupDate is a DATETIME field containing the date of the backup.

What I want is to return the date of the last backup(bu.backupDate) (there are usually several, since most of my admins are well trained and press the "backup" button before they modify the article!) and also the number of backups in the database (COUNT(bu.id) AS totalBackups)

However, my query is currently just returning one result, which is the first backup (not the most recent) All I want is for it to select the row from content which has the most recent corresponding backup date. Query works fine without the COUNT(bu.id) so Im guessing this is the problem, but not sure how to fix it...

Any help would be really appreciated!

Happy Christmas!

**EDIT**

Thanks for all your help guys! I tried all of your suggestions (and learned a huge amount of new stuff along the way!)

You all put me on the right track by reminding me about the MAX() function, which eventually led to the following functional query:

```
SELECT co.title, co.content, co.id, MAX(bu.backupDate) AS backupDate, bu.backupBy, COUNT(bu.id) AS totalBackups
FROM content co, wol_content_backup bu
WHERE co.car_model = '6-110'
AND co.subcategory = 'introduction'
```

which outputs exactly what I wanted!

Thanks so much for helping a coder in distress on Christmas day! :)

Seb

Comment: what id fields are in each table?  Is co.id = bu.id or is there another id field in bu that indicates content id a particular backup goes with?

Comment: co.id = bu.articleID (there is a bu.id but it's just an index, not related to co.id)

Comment: coralated subquery and max should do the trick. or a subquery with max (but it will be slower) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368331/show-only-most-recent-date-from-joined-mysql-table) gives you an idea how.  The Accepted answer uses the slower method, there is a 2nd example showing the correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the syntax off the type of my head, but consider a subquery to get the most recent backup date and add this to your WHERE clause of the main query. Then you can loose the ORDER clause as you will get one result (and also loose the COUNT).

Answer (score 0):

This should give you want you want.  The key is to do a derived table that gets you the most recent backup for the articleid(s) you're dealing with.  And then uses that information in the outer query to get your title, content, and backupby dates: (comments interspersed as non-code)

```
SELECT co.title, co.content, co.id, 
bu.backupBy,
mostrecent.MostRecentBackup,  
mostrecent.NumOfBackups
FROM content co inner join
```

This is the derived table that does the work of getting the last backup and the ID of the record that contains it

```
(select bu.id
       max(bu.backupdate) as MostRecentBackUP,
       count(bu.id) as NumOfBackups
from 
wol_content_backup bu
Group by bu.id
) mostrecent
```

Then you go to the content table with the articleid

```
on co.id = mostrecent.articleid
```

and go back to the wol_content_backup table for the backupBy field

```
inner join wol_content_backup buouter on
mostrecent.id = buouter.id

WHERE co.car_model = '6-110'
AND co.subcategory = 'introduction'
ORDER BY MostRecentBackup DESC
```