# MySQL - Find most recent upload for each user

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following `files` table where files are stored for multiple users (the table is only showing files for 1 user).

```
+--------+----------+----------+------------------------------+
| fileID | fileName | folderID | userID | uploadDate          |        
+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| 1      | file1    | 1        | 1      | 2014-02-03 12:00:00 |
| 2      | file2    | 2        | 1      | 2014-01-05 12:00:00 |
| 3      | file3    | 3        | 1      | 2014-01-08 12:00:00 |
| 4      | file4    | 2        | 1      | 2014-01-04 12:00:00 |
| 5      | file5    | 1        | 1      | 2014-01-07 12:00:00 |
| 6      | file6    | 3        | 1      | 2014-01-09 12:00:00 |
+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

I want to find the most recent file uploaded for each folder by date.
The outcome should be like this...

```
+--------+----------+----------+------------------------------+
| fileID | fileName | folderID | userID | uploadDate          |        
+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| 2      | file2    | 2        | 1      | 2014-03-05 12:00:00 |
| 5      | file5    | 1        | 1      | 2014-03-07 12:00:00 |
| 6      | file6    | 3        | 1      | 2014-03-09 12:00:00 |
+--------+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This a common question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657482/sql-find-the-max-record-per-group You should bookmark and stuff the following which has many very common and also very useful queries. Good luck! http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php

Comment: There's a whole chapter in the MySQL manual dedicated to explaining this problem. And it's been asked and answered several times here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show only most recent date from joined MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368331/show-only-most-recent-date-from-joined-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is a surprisingly difficult thing to do with SQL.  My best solution for this is to create a temporary table and then join against it:

CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`fileID` int, `fileName` varchar(5), `folderID` int, `userID` int, `uploadDate` datetime)
;

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`fileID`, `fileName`, `folderID`, `userID`, `uploadDate`)
VALUES
    (1, 'file1', 1, 1, '2014-02-03 12:00:00'),
    (2, 'file2', 2, 1, '2014-01-05 12:00:00'),
    (3, 'file3', 3, 1, '2014-01-08 12:00:00'),
    (4, 'file4', 2, 1, '2014-01-04 12:00:00'),
    (5, 'file5', 1, 1, '2014-01-07 12:00:00'),
    (6, 'file6', 3, 1, '2014-01-09 12:00:00')
;

create temporary table last_files (
  fileID int, fileName varchar(5), folderID int, userID int , 
  unique key( folderID, userID )
);

REPLACE INTO last_files ( fileID, fileName, folderID, userID ) 
select fileID, fileName, folderID, userID 
from Table1 order by uploadDate asc;

select * from last_files;
```

Instead of a subquery, it uses a temporary table to collate the results and then joins back to the original table.  It's a pattern I've used on massive tables in the past with pretty good results.

If you're looking for a particular user, you can `SORT BY uploadDate DESC LIMIT 1` instead, but that is obviously limited.